# Loading an SF item to an AGOL Feature Layer via Arc Rest API

Tags: r, gis, arcgis, arcgis-online

Im having difficulty using R to load the geometries from a kml to a feature layer stored in AGOL.  Im using sf in R to process the kml file, convert it to a geojson, take the geometry from the geojson, add it to a adds package, then load the package to the feature layer via the applyEdits request.  However, whenever I do I consistently get errors saying that my geometry package isn't sturctured correctly.  I can get it to work with a mock polygon I create via sf, but never when using an existing file.

```
url <- "https://services1.arcgis.com/*********/arcgis/rest/services/Test_Load/FeatureServer/0"

# Read KML file into an sf object
kml_data <- sf::st_read("C:/git/APEX_2024/Zip_Map_Attributes/Data/KML Files/AK_Hwy_Johnson_APE_STIP33824.kml")

geojson <- sf_geojson(kml_data)

parsed_geojson <- jsonlite::fromJSON(geojson)




polygon <- list(
  geometry = list(
    rings = parsed_geojson$features$geometry$coordinates,
    spatialReference = list(
      wkid = 4326
    )
  ),
  attributes = list(
    Test = "Added from R"
  )
)


edits <- list(
  adds = list(polygon)
)


# Add token to the headers if necessary
headers <- c(
  "Content-type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  "Accept" = "text/plain"
)


response <- POST(
  url = paste0(url, "/applyEdits"),
  query = list(
    f = "json",
    adds = toJSON(edits$adds),
    updateParameters = toJSON(list())  # Add an empty updateParameters to fix the "Invalid parameters" error
  ),
  add_headers(.headers=headers)
```

)